# How to create directory(s) within java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, directory

How do you create a directory when java swing gui application starts? I've been able to create it with ease for console apps, but the code doesn't execute while trying to build a gui app. NOTE: no errors are shown either.

The result I'm looking for is when the gui application first starts, it creates a directory C:\foo\bar.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Please show us your code. It should not make a difference for `File.mkdirs()` whether called from a Swing or a console application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just hook up to the window listener
Ex:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            new File("C:\\foo\\bar").mkdir();
        }

});
```